# MVC - Unit of work – duplicate records issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-of-work

I’m working on this project where we have a form that saves an entity and before saving it we check that the record doesn’t exist by checking against a unique attribute of the entity on the database.

This works fine except on the scenario where we press very quickly the submit form button multiple times. On this case the database check does not work and it creates multiple entries of the record in the database.

I think it is a design problem of the application but I’m new to the unit of work pattern and I can’t understand why is not working.

This is the check we do on the service layer:

```
    IEnumerable<Story> Stories = _unitOfWork.StoryRepository.Get(s => e.GUID.Equals(GUID));
    if (Stories.Count() > 0)
    {
        _unitOfWork. StoryRepository.Insert(newStory);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
```

can anyone help with this issue?

btw, I'm not after a javascript based solution, only server-side.

Thanks

EDIT:
the service uses ninject and has a constructor that passes the unit of work:

```
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public StoryService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

My UnitOfWork class is declared as:

```
public class UnitOfWork : Disposable, IUnitOfWork
```

DatabaseFactory.cs:

```
public class DatabaseFactory : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory
{
    private myContext _dataContext;
    private readonly object _door = new object();

    public myContext Get()
    {
        lock (_door)
        {
            return _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = new myContext());
        }
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (_dataContext != null)
            _dataContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Should I create an instance of UnitOfWork every time I call a method of my service as Pluc is suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you are creating your unit of work too early. Your unit of work should be a IDisposable enity so that you can use it when you want it, and get rid of it right after. Using statement becomes quite nice for this situation :

```
using(var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
{
    IEnumerable<Story> Stories = unitOfWork.StoryRepository.Get(s => e.GUID.Equals(GUID));
    if (Stories.Count() > 0)
    {
        unitOfWork.StoryRepository.Insert(newStory);
        unitOfWork.Save();
    }
}
```

If your UnitOfWork is created really early, and the StoryRepository is used in another occasion early, then the Stories are already loaded. If you click the submit twice, depending on the page load speed, then you have yourself a nice race condition where if you UnitOfWork from request #1 doesn't save his context before the request #2 lazy loads his, then both request will have the exact same list of stories and the condition will pass for both.

If you create your UnitOfWork just as you need it, it wont even have the Stories loaded and therefore, the only window there is to make a bad condition test, is the 0.001ms between your .Get() repository method and your unitOfWork.Save().

Always keep in mind that a UnitOfWork is ment to optimize your data access by batching all your queries at once. It is not a data caching tool. Create it, use it, dump it. Theres no harm in creating it twice or more in a single web request.

Comment: Is this UnitOfWork used at any places before your action method described in this post?

Comment: I suggest you use the SQL Profiler to look at the queries executed (if you have access to that). The problem is that the moment StoryRepository gets his list of Stories is too far away from the moment it inserts his Story. That means the StoreRepository already loaded his data. Perhaps lazy loading is turned off? Or something else before makes a query? Those are the only 2 options I see atm.

Comment: well, the thing is that this issue only happens when I click the submit button repeatedly. It works fine otherwise...

Comment: That's what I am saying. The procedure work fine, it's just that the request processing is too long and before it gets to insert the new Story, the 2nd request already got itself an instance of the UnitOfWork and already used the StoryRepository to gather a list of story (OR the UnitOfWork/Repository is not properly done in terms of lazy loading).

Comment: To use the Using procedure, I believe you can inject the UnitOfWork in a property (or even a Field but for testing purposes, you'd want to avoid that because you will not be able to manually inject a testing UnitOfWork). Just put [Inject] in front of your property.

Comment: as I did not design the application how do I check this? ==> "(OR the UnitOfWork/Repository is not properly done in terms of lazy loading)"

Comment: Ctrl+F, LazyLoad, Entire Solution.

Comment: The lazy loading configuration is change / obtained from the property `DataBaseContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` (DataBaseContext being an instance of your database context)

Comment: There is no lazy loading declaration on my website. where do I set it up?

Comment: You dont, the default is enabled. Without more code, that's as far as I can help you.

Comment: would it be possible that the problem is in my ninject declaration? At the moment I use: kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();  
            kernel.Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory>();

Comment: Get rid of InRequestScope(), but i doubt this is the problem. Can I see what your DatabaseFactory looks like?

Comment: Your factory class is a bit weird (shouldn't that be a singleton or a static class?) but once again, I doubt this is the issue...

Comment: yeah I don't think that's the problem... any more ideas?